# Why $f_n=\frac{1}{n}1_{[0,n]}$ shows that $L^1(\mathbb R)$ is not reflexive?

Tags: real-analysis

In my course it's written that $f_n=\frac{1}{n}1_{[0,n]}$ shows that $L^1(\mathbb R)$ is not reflexive. Could someone explain why ? I know that reflexive mean that bounded sequence has subsequence that converges weakly. So suppose it's reflexive. Since $\|f_n\|_{L^1}=1$, there is a subsequence (still denoted $(f_n)$ that converges. Denote $f$ its limit. Then, for all $\varphi \in L^\infty (\mathbb R)$, $$\int(f_n-f)\varphi \to 0,$$
in particular, if $\varphi =1$, then $$\int (f_n-f)\to 0.$$
Also, by fatou $$0\leq \liminf_{n\to \infty }\int_{\mathbb R} |f_n|,$$
but at the end, I can't get any contradiction... I guess the contradiction is that $f=0$, but how can I prove that $f=0$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Define for $\varepsilon >0$
$$P_{N,\varepsilon}= \{ x\in [-N, N] \ : \ f(x)>\varepsilon \}.$$
Now we have $\varphi_{N,\varepsilon}= 1_{P_{N,\varepsilon}} \in L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ and thus, we get
$$ 0\leq m(P_{N,\varepsilon}) \varepsilon \leq \int f \varphi_{N,\varepsilon} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int f_n \varphi_{N,\varepsilon} 
\leq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}  \frac{1}{n}\int_{-N}^N 1 =0.       $$
Which implies $m(P_{N,\varepsilon})=0$ for all $N$ and $\varepsilon$ and hence, we get
$$ m(\{ x\in \mathbb{R} \ : \ f(x) >0 \}) =  m\left( \bigcup_{(k,l)\in \mathbb{N}_{>0}\times \mathbb{N}_{>0}} P_{k, 1/l} \right) =0.$$
Similarly one shows $m(\{ x\in \mathbb{R} \ : \ f(x) <0 \})=0$. Thus, we conclude that $f=0$ a.e. and hence $f=0$ in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$. This gives us the desired contradicition as
$$ \int f \cdot 1 = 0 \neq 1 = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int f_n \cdot 1. $$

Answer (score 0):

An other way is to consider $$f_n=n\boldsymbol 1_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]}.$$
You have that $\|f_n\|_{L^1}=1$ pour all $n$. Suppose there is a subsequence (still denoted $(f_n)$) that converges weakly to a function $f$. Then, for all $\varphi \in \mathcal C_c^\infty (\mathbb R\setminus \{0\})$, $$\lim_{n\to \infty }\int f_n\varphi =0=\int f\varphi ,$$
and thus $f=0$ on $\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}$, i.e. $f=0$ p.p. Now, as you remarked, for $\varphi =1$, we have that $$1=\lim_{n\to \infty }\int f_n=\int f,$$which contradict $f=0$.

Comment: Indeed, this is much better :D (btw, your sequence is the sequence mention in my lecture, I didn't copy well in my question).